# I need guidance on designing a 2 kV capacitor charging circuit

Tags: voltage, capacitor, transformer, charge, spark

I have to design high voltage circuit for the first time in my life.

Its purpose is to provide enough voltage to make a spark plug ignite a coal powder mixture.

There are some requirements for this circuit:

1. Capacitor C6's capacitance above 50μF at least.
2. Make charging time as short as possible (about 50ms to 100ms.)
3. Charging voltage must be above 2kV.

I followed some circuits from the Internet, and finally I reached this circuit design:

[image]

It doesn't work well enough.

Vibrator frequency is about 3kHz to 4kHz, duty cycle is 50%.

I used an ideal transformer in OrCAD - the primary coil is 465μH, the secondary coil is 46500μH.

It takes 200 milliseconds reach to 400V.

I need advice on this problem.

Comment: Sooooo....  It's not clear what that circuit is supposed to do.  Could you explain?  Normally you'd use a flyback converter a boost converter or a voltage multiplier and inverter or other common topology to get 2KV, depending on how fast you're hoping to charge your cap.

Comment: K H// I using inductance kick. Dalington switch has control by vibrator and it activate, current flow at primary coil of transformer. Then switch off,current flow cutted, it make voltage spike. Voltage spike going to secondary coil of transformer and It charge the capacitor.

Comment: How fast is your oscillator switching and what is the duty cycle?  On the secondary you have an odd arrangement of two diodes and a capacitor.  What does it do?  You also have a 1000n series capacitor.  Have you checked that your frequency is high enough to pass through it?  You also have a 20p capacitor bypassing your rectifying diode and I'm curious as to what that's intended to do.

Comment: KH // frequency is about 3k~4k duty cycle is 50%. That weird array is part of voltage multiplier circuit, according to youtube. Without that weird circuit, I got only 200V of capacitor..
And I don't know 20p capacitor works. I pick that design somewhere..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DI8Yt1AQrH8&t=40s

Comment: KH // I search flyback converter and that design is complatly match my design.
But PSPICE simulation has failed. Output voltage only has 200V..

Comment: Hmm voltage multipliers are normally driven by a balanced bidirectional voltage.  I'm not sure what the effect is of having your transformer driven in only one direction like this is.  What is your output voltage and charge time currently?  Add the extra information to the question by the way, don't answer in comments.

Comment: Extra voltage multiplier stages are one option.  Your transformer ratio is fairly high, and the resistances seem out.  If your secondary has 100 times as many windings higher resistance would probably be more accurate.  Possibly lower than 1 ohm for the primary as it can be fatter wire.

Comment: Q6 Seems badly chosen.  The datasheet I found said 50mA max continuous and you're trying to short circuit current spikes through a transformer and 1 ohm so your desired current is probably much higher than that.  Try simulating with a nice chunky mosfet or a bigger transistor maybe.

Comment: KH // you mean 50mA is flow secondary coil of transformer?
Actually, Its 288mA peak.
Plus, I am adjusting the parameters of the transformer to get the desired result.
So, I don't know that parameter is real...

Comment: It's possible to get the desired results with a real transformer so making the values as real as possible isn't a bad idea.  I meant the current on the primary which has to be higher than the current on the secondary by nature of being lower voltage.  The Closest thing I found to a Q2n2484/15C datasheet was a transistor with 50mA max continuous current so your transistor appears to not be well documented and probably not a good choice.  Something designed to handle much higher current might improve your performance.

Comment: Your diode 15ETH06 appears to be rated for only 600V which may be a problem as you get your output higher.

Comment: Thank you so much K H! 
I will try to decide transistor & diode.

Comment: 2kV won't do anything with a normal spark plug. Just copy a regular ignition circuit.

Comment: Please add some details about the background behind the design requirements. (Are you, like, designing a coal-powder internal combustion engine?) As specified now, this circuit would deliver about 1 kW on average to the output. An igniter that outputs a kilowatt is a really big one (way above typical automotive ones). Do you really need that? Where does the value of the output capacitance, firing rate and voltage come from? (As stated by others, 2 kV is way too low for typical spark plugs.)

Comment: As noted about spark plugs, look at the Paschen's law graph on wikipedia to get a lower bound for the voltage you need with a given gap size and pressure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law. For atmosphere approximate as 100% N2, a 1mm gap is a bit under 10^2 on the x-axis, so you need at least ~5 kV without compression, preferably double or triple that.

Comment: @TooTea Some guy called Rudolf Diesel already tried that. It didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what circuit topology that is - it's missing essential parts of both a flyback and a forward converter.

First, some numbers.  When fully charged to 2 kV, a 50 uF capacitor holds 100 W-s (watt-seconds) of energy.  To replace that in 0.1 s requires a 1 kW power source; in 50 ms it is a 2 kW source.  A 2 kW boost converter is a significant design task for an experienced power system designer, and way beyond a student.  I'm not picking on you here, just putting things in perspective.

Separate from that, if this is just a classroom exercise, your approach has problems.  While Q6 and Q7 (seriously, THANK YOU for using reference designators) charge up the transformer primary, there is no mechanism for reversing the direction of primary current to reset the transformer core and for the secondary.  The diode-and-capacitor stuff on the secondary looks like a Cockroft-Walton circuit, but if so it has connection errors.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator

Also, for a C-W circuit consider the current through the capacitors.  At 4 kHz, a 1 uF capacitor has an impedance of 40 ohms.  At 1 A of secondary current, there will be significant voltage drop across them.

Also, most importantly, a C-W circuit requires a symmetrical AC waveform to drive it, one with (hopefully) equal source impedances for both directions of electron flow.  This requires symmetrical drive of the transformer primary, which your circuit does not have.  As above, it drives the transformer primary in one direction only.  As a basic starting point, look at a Royer oscillator circuit.  This is very popular in UPS designs, which is essentially what you are building.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royer_oscillator

Comment: Great answer. To stress the key points even more, there's absolutely no way of getting 1 kW from a 24 V battery through the 1 Ohm resistor on the primary. The whole primary needs to be designed for ~100 A currents. Also, a voltage multiplier is something you use instead of a transformer (when you need very high voltage and minuscule current and a transformer is impractical), not right on the secondary of a transformer. Just double the number of turns of the secondary and do away with the multiplier, as that just introduces losses for no good reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't know what I miss something..
I definitly thought simple design of flyback converter is enough to my project..
However, as I look my circuit, diode on secondary transformer doesn't blocking inverse current.
I will try C-W multiplier combined royer circuit.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that when engineering things, you're supposed to design a solution: solve the problem. It doesn't mean that you need to design a *circuit*. If the solution requires a circuit, with no other alternatives - sure, go for it. But perhaps stop and ask yourself: is spark ignition a unique problem? No, it's not. You can buy off the shelf spark igniters designed for industrial use, and even the ignition modules from cars may work if the spark energy is sufficient. A typical car ignition module has three pins: 12V, 0V, and trigger (active low, but not always). It's tested, reliable, and robust: it has to survive under the hood of a car, running at 100C.

So, before you start on any circuit design, look at the costs: your time + overheads (a reasonable guess is overhead = 100% of employee salary) + production costs + testing costs + service costs due to reliability level you engineered. How expensive will a failure in the field be? Can your company afford that cost? Do they have experienced engineers who can do a design review? You will most likely find that the cheapest and most reliable way to go about is to **not design an igniter**, but to buy one.

Comment: Also, gas oven spark igniters are available, in case the OP only looks at automotive ones.